# How to pass HumanCurve to HumanClicker using pyclick package?

Tags: python-3.x

```
from pyclick import HumanClicker

hc = HumanClicker()

hc.move((100,100),2)

hc.click()
```

You can also customize the mouse curve by passing a HumanCurve to HumanClicker. You can control:
number of internal knots, to change the overall shape of the curve,
distortion to simulate shivering,
tween to simulate acceleration and speed of movement

I am currently using python 3.6 but i am facing a problem, I don't know How to pass HumanCurve to HumanClicker can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by doing the following:

```
# get the current position
fromPoint = pyautogui.position()

# the final position of the mouse
toPoint = (100,100)

# Take a look at all the options in this function: https://github.com/patrikoss/pyclick/blob/master/pyclick/humancurve.py#L18
options = {
    "knotsCount": 2,
}

human_curve = HumanCurve(fromPoint=fromPoint, toPoint=toPoint, **options)

# initialize HumanClicker object
hc = HumanClicker()

# use the move() function with the your custom curve
hc.move((x,y), duration=1, humanCurve=human_curve)
```